# Postgres in docker-compose not running init scripts

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, go-gorm

I am trying to run a basic init script for a `PostgreSQL 15.0` image which is being initialised via `docker-compose`.

The issue I am specifically trying to correct is the enabling of `UUIDv4` via `uuid-ossp` for automatic generation of UUID values in my application model which is using `go-orm`.

I have the following excerpt within my docker-compose

```
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:15.0-alpine3.16
    restart: always
    user: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./pg_init_scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    env_file:
      - ./.db-variables-dev.env
```

pg_init_scripts is in the same directory as my compose file with the below structure and SQL file.

```
pg_init_scripts
└── extension.sql

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

What is missing from my config?

When my app initialises I get the following error.

```
/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/driver/postgres@v1.4.4/migrator.go:151 ERROR: function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist (SQLSTATE 42883)
```

Full error

```
Creating postgres ... done
Creating api      ... done
Creating nginx    ... done
Attaching to postgres, api, nginx
nginx       | 2022/11/22 10:38:19 [warn] 7#7: "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found for certificate "/etc/ssl/fullchain.pem"
nginx       | nginx: [warn] "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found for certificate "/etc/ssl/fullchain.pem"
nginx       | 2022/11/22 10:38:19 [notice] 7#7: using the "epoll" event method
nginx       | 2022/11/22 10:38:19 [notice] 7#7: nginx/1.20.1
nginx       | 2022/11/22 10:38:19 [notice] 7#7: built by gcc 10.2.1 20201203 (Alpine 10.2.1_pre1) 
nginx       | 2022/11/22 10:38:19 [notice] 7#7: OS: Linux 5.15.0-53-generic
nginx       | 2022/11/22 10:38:19 [notice] 7#7: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
api         | API server listening at: [::]:40000
api         | 2022-11-22T10:38:19Z warning layer=rpc Listening for remote connections (connections are not authenticated nor encrypted)
postgres    | 
postgres    | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres    | 
postgres    | 2022-11-22 10:38:18.419 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.0 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 11.2.1_git20220219) 11.2.1 20220219, 64-bit
postgres    | 2022-11-22 10:38:18.419 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres    | 2022-11-22 10:38:18.419 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
nginx       | 2022/11/22 10:38:19 [notice] 7#7: start worker processes
postgres    | 2022-11-22 10:38:18.440 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
nginx       | 2022/11/22 10:38:19 [notice] 7#7: start worker process 8
postgres    | 2022-11-22 10:38:18.464 UTC [15] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2022-11-22 10:34:30 UTC
postgres    | 2022-11-22 10:38:19.120 UTC [15] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
nginx       | 2022/11/22 10:38:19 [notice] 7#7: start worker process 9
postgres    | 2022-11-22 10:38:19.128 UTC [15] LOG:  redo starts at 0/19D01D0
postgres    | 2022-11-22 10:38:19.129 UTC [15] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/19E70D0: wanted 24, got 0
postgres    | 2022-11-22 10:38:19.129 UTC [15] LOG:  redo done at 0/19E7098 system usage: CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s
nginx       | 2022/11/22 10:38:19 [notice] 7#7: start worker process 10
postgres    | 2022-11-22 10:38:19.156 UTC [13] LOG:  checkpoint starting: end-of-recovery immediate wait
nginx       | 2022/11/22 10:38:19 [notice] 7#7: start worker process 11
postgres    | 2022-11-22 10:38:19.222 UTC [13] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 21 buffers (0.1%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.019 s, sync=0.014 s, total=0.074 s; sync files=15, longest=0.007 s, average=0.001 s; distance=91 kB, estimate=91 kB
nginx       | 2022/11/22 10:38:19 [notice] 7#7: start worker process 12
postgres    | 2022-11-22 10:38:19.231 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
nginx       | 2022/11/22 10:38:19 [notice] 7#7: start worker process 13
nginx       | 2022/11/22 10:38:19 [notice] 7#7: start worker process 14
nginx       | 2022/11/22 10:38:19 [notice] 7#7: start worker process 15
nginx       | 2022/11/22 10:38:19 [notice] 7#7: start worker process 16
nginx       | 2022/11/22 10:38:19 [notice] 7#7: start worker process 17
nginx       | 2022/11/22 10:38:19 [notice] 7#7: start worker process 18
nginx       | 2022/11/22 10:38:19 [notice] 7#7: start worker process 19
api         | [GIN-debug] [WARNING] Creating an Engine instance with the Logger and Recovery middleware already attached.
api         | 
api         | [GIN-debug] [WARNING] Running in "debug" mode. Switch to "release" mode in production.
api         |  - using env: export GIN_MODE=release
api         |  - using code:    gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
api         | 
postgres    | 2022-11-22 10:38:22.556 UTC [19] ERROR:  function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist at character 52
postgres    | 2022-11-22 10:38:22.556 UTC [19] HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
postgres    | 2022-11-22 10:38:22.556 UTC [19] STATEMENT:  CREATE TABLE "companies" ("id" uuid UNIQUE DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),"uuid" uuid UNIQUE DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),"created_at" timestamptz,"updated_at" timestamptz,"deleted_at" timestamptz,"name" text UNIQUE,"primary_contact" text,"contact_email" text UNIQUE,"domain" text UNIQUE,PRIMARY KEY ("id"))
api         | 
api         | 2022/11/22 10:38:22 /go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/driver/postgres@v1.4.4/migrator.go:151 ERROR: function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist (SQLSTATE 42883)
api         | [2.152ms] [rows:0] CREATE TABLE "companies" ("id" uuid UNIQUE DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),"uuid" uuid UNIQUE DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),"created_at" timestamptz,"updated_at" timestamptz,"deleted_at" timestamptz,"name" text UNIQUE,"primary_contact" text,"contact_email" text UNIQUE,"domain" text UNIQUE,PRIMARY KEY ("id"))
postgres    | 2022-11-22 10:43:19.293 UTC [13] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
postgres    | 2022-11-22 10:43:20.964 UTC [13] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 17 buffers (0.1%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=1.612 s, sync=0.022 s, total=1.671 s; sync files=14, longest=0.016 s, average=0.002 s; distance=87 kB, estimate=91 kB
```

Comment: It is running them, surely? You have an error near the bottom there saying you haven't loaded the uuid extension (or have the wrong schema search-path or some such). ERROR at `2022-11-22 10:38:22.556`

Comment: That is being generated by my model, UUID      
string `gorm:"type:uuid;unique;default:gen_random_uuid()"`

Comment: In that case you may need to delete the existing database installation (in volume postgres_data) and re-run. Check if those logs have anything. It might well not be re-running the init scripts if the db is already initialised.

Comment: The log file answers this question directly:  "PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization"

Comment: jjanes and Richard Huxton you were both correct. I removed the database but it needed a bounce of docker.socket/docker.service